# Swagger takes long time to start. What could be the reasons?

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

When I start my Api via IIS and the **Swagger comes up, it takes mostly very long time around 30 to 60 seconds**. Why could be the reasons, where I could search for the cause?

@Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "DataPicker API", Version = "v1" });
        });...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DataPicker API V1");

            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Dtos that you return in apis, it may contains domain model you (should return Dtos only)

Comment: With Dtos you mean "Data transfer object"? Where I look for the Dtos which I return at my APi?

Comment: yes, the "Data transfer object" that you return it in your api, you should not return a domain model (full object).